# What should the Hreflang and canonical be with session parameters?

Tags: canonical-url, hreflang, url-parameters, session

We have a oxid onlineshop with different domains/subdomains depending on currency and language.

Now we have a problem with hreflang tags, because of parameters

1. the session of the basket between domains is set by `?force_sid=(random string for session id)`
2. for different views in categories like `?ldtype=grid&_artperpage=100&pgNr=0&cl=alist&searchparam=&cnid=3ae4a2e1dd7501139.35363255`

If the URL is accessed without the parameters then the canonical and hreflang tags are correct.

If the parameters are set then the canonical and hreflang tags are wrong.

What are the correct tags for example: `www.example.de/category-name/?force_sid=e9k6p7d5dbpcu3s41p22tbll71 ?`

We have:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.example.de/category-name/">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="x-default" href="https://www.example.de/category-name/">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="de" href="https://www.example.de/category-name/">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="de-CH" href="https://www.example.ch/category-name/">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="fr-CH" href="https://fr.example.ch/category-name/">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="de-AT" href="https://www.example.at/category-name/">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="fr" href="https://www.example.fr/category-name/">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="https://www.example.com/category-name/">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="es" href="https://www.example.es/category-name/">
```

Comment: Websites have been using cookies rather than parameters for session ids for nearly 20 years now.   Session id parameters shouldn't be used on any site that requires SEO because they make the site uncrawlable.   I don't think it is even a matter of getting the canonicals correct.  I don't think search engines can deal with session parameters even today.

Answer (score 1):

don't tell me you really index such parametrized urls? If yes - this has an outstanding negative impact.

If they are noindex-ed (what would be correct), then don't care about their canonicals and hreflangs. Your parameter-less urls are for Google - there should canonicals and hreflangs be correct.

Comment: ok thank you, I see. so its enough if we set links with parameters with metatag robots to noindex, nofollow? But same page without parameters to index, follow. right?

Comment: My choice would be: do it exactly as you said. But care about following: if you set parametrized urls to `noindex, nofollow`, set ANY internal link of parametrized url should be `rel="nofollow"` too.